# Mod Rewrite - How to Rewrite All URLs With Doing Manually In .htaccess?

Tags: php, linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a custom CMS that another developer built a few years ago. I need to change the urls to clean segment based urls from query strings. I could just add the rules for all the pages in the .htaccess file, which would be a pain as that's a lot of pages. Plus when a new page is added, obviously I won't be there waiting to quickly add a rewrite rule.

How do I set this up so it automatically adds it's own rewrite rules. Like the modules and plugins in Drupal and Wordpress do?

Thanks!

Comment: Drupal and WordPress don't dynamically add rewrite rules. They have a single rewrite rule (or simple set of them, at least) that let PHP handle **all** requests matching a certain pattern. Is there a pattern to the URLs you want to rewrite?

Comment: Ah yeah there is, sorry I've just figured it out, just need to add the rewrite rule matching the pattern, then change the way links are added to the pages. Thanks for your time anyway VoteyDisciple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so following on from my comment:

Get the rewrite rules for your urls either by hand (if you're mad) or using this great tool:

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ and add them to .htaccess in your root folder.

Then go through and change the links in your code swapping out the query string parts, ?q= etc, for whichever delimiter you chose, - or /. Et voila, it should now work.

Hope this helps someone else...